# How to assign port for HTTPI?

Tags: ruby, http, httpi

I'm using [httpi](http://httpirb.com/) library.

Usually in http libraries we can set a port for http connection, but in httpi I can't.

How to assign port for HTTPI connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd include the port number in the URL, like this:

```
request = HTTPI::Request.new("http://example.com:1234/")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got an error: "ArgumentError: Invalid URL: localhost:17172"